# How can I get the highest role of a message.author?

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

i would like to get the name of a highest role in nextcord. Give it a variable for that?
If you anything now about this, respond please.

What i have tried:

I have read the docs of nextcord, but i din't found it.

Thank you for you respondig

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The description for `Member.roles`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Member.roles) (equivalent to [the `Message.author`'s `roles` property](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.Member.roles)) is pretty clear (emphasis mine):

> A list of `Role` that the member belongs to. Note that the first element of this list is always the default ‘@everyone’ role.
>
> **These roles are sorted by their position in the role hierarchy.**"

Thus, this would make the "*highest*" role accessible like so:

```
message_object.author.roles[-1]
```